# PHP 7.3 on Netbeans IDE

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

does anybody know how can I use php 7.3 in Netbeans IDE 8.2? I can only use php 7.0 right now. My XAMPP is supporting PHP 7.3 and the framework i want to use requires it but the IDE will not let me use it.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans IDE 8.2 ([release notes](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/)) only supports PHP/7.0 features. It couldn't be any other way, since PHP 7.3 was released on December 2018 and that IDE version is from October 2016.

That doesn't mean that you *absolutely* need to downgrade PHP to 7.0. It just means that if your code uses features that introduce a new syntax then NetBeans will report bogus parse errors. Everything else will work just fine.

You may want to try the latest version (NetBeans 11 at the time of writing). Support for PHP 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3 support was introduced at NetBeans 10 ([notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Feature%3A+PHP)).